# How to add Sentry monitoring to a Spring project

Tags: spring, exception, logging, monitoring, sentry

I looked at the Documentation and some Github examples about adding Sentry logging and monitoring to a Spring project.

Does anyone have an example or a link that can help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work.

These are the exact steps you have to follow:

1. In your `pom.xml`, add the following dependency for Sentry. (I am using Logback):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
       <artifactId>sentry-logback</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.16</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. For reference (this is just for testing purposes), go in settings, click Client Settings in the SDK setup and get your dsn URL.
3. After that, make a file in src/resources named `sentry.properties` and add the following to it:`dsn=<YOUR_DSN_URL>`.
4. Make a `logback.xml` file (if it doesn't already exist) and add the following configuration to it:

```xml
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
<property name="app.name" value="MyApp"/>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{40}: %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Sentry"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you include `sentry-spring` as well or just the logback module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using logback with Spring, you can add a new appender to the logback-spring.xml file like:

```
<appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

You also need to set your datasource name:

This can be done in several ways. Ex in your bootstrap.properties file set a property:

`dsn=https://public:private@host:port/1`

See this documentation for more info:
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/

Comment: Oh, I did that. What I'm not able to figure out is how to send an error to Sentry using my dev environment.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to define your datasource name. This can be changed per environment.

Comment: But what values should I set for public and private? I don't understand how I can get connected to Sentry like this.

Comment: Also, I'm using 
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.16</version>
</dependency>